# Is there a context-agnostic concept of automatic (log-)text parsing that supports human reader filtering out redundancy?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, entropy

This question is about ideas I regularly think about, and I would like to know what concepts already exist. *Also I am not sure at all if this really makes sense, by now it is just a crazy idea*

**Motivation:**
In all my last jobs as a software developer, I spent much time on staring at log lines, trying to find the 1 relevant line. Good logs aren't flooded with irrelevant information, but the world isn't perfect of course.

Scenario A:
You are reading a file where certain log messages are repeated massively. Obviously, the non-repeated lines are more interesting.
The lines that do repeat often have single fields that change, like indices or timestamps. These are even less interesting if they follow a common pattern (e.g. monotholically increasing), while single outliers that break this pattern are more interesting.

Scenario B:
You have a folder with a big number of log files, each from the same domain (e.g. different sessions of the same kind or program runs of the same program).
Log lines that can be found in many files (again, except for some changing fields like timestamps) are less interesting than lines only found in a small percentage of files.

Scenario C:
You have a log processing framework where components like fluentbit or rlogd are filtering logs and appending fields to every line. In the end you look at the text where the first 100 characters of every line are virtually identical.

Often, someone started to write domain-specific log parsers to help at some point, but that's just a limited tool.

**Intention:**

With the concept of text files now being >50 years old, and computers being totally overpowered to process them, is there any generic approach to help in these cases? I know there are e.g. parsers that understand almost any format of a time stamp. But I wonder if a more agnostic concept has already been developed.

I'm not very confident with the terminology here. But, these days its quite easy to define a new "context-free grammar", to implement a custom lexer etc. Couldn't there be something like a genetic algorithm to deduce a grammar from existing text, with the right balance between being too "finegrained" and too "repetitive"? This could be a first step to identify re-occurring structures.

A simpler approach could be to use compression algorithms to deduce importance based on predictability.

In the end, I would wish for a graphical representation of the text where less interesting structures (lines, fields) are gradually grayed out or even hidden by folding techniques, and related structures have similar color. But that's only UI representation of course and not actually part of my question.

**Question:**

- Does this makes sense at all? Is my point understandable? Did I mis-use terminology?
- Is this a silly idea, because proven not to be feasible, or because better approaches exist?
- Is there any development or concept that is roughly heading in this direction?